# Delete a picture from the look-back movie

Tags: facebook, facebook-lookback

How can I delete one of the pics on my look back movie? There is no edit button or delete button, only share.

Answer (score 1):

Lookback now features an edit button, or just head over to [Edit Lookback](https://www.facebook.com/lookback/edit/).

Select your moments, and choose update